# Api call when open screen using Provider in Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-provider

I am confusing when using provider. Some developers use FutureBuilder to fetch API when open app's screen as following

```
var provider = locator<AppIntroProvider>(); //GetIt Dependancy Infection
 @override
 void initState() {
   super.initState();
 }

 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   return Scaffold(
     body: FutureBuilder(
       future:  provider.getAppIntroItems(),
       builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<dynamic> snapshot) => snapshot
           .data ==
           null
           ? Container(
         color: Colors.red,
       ) : MyDataListWidget(),
     ),
   );
 }
```

But I implemented API call in InitState and listen data using Consumer, Like this.

```
var provider = locator<AppIntroProvider>(); //GetIt DI

 @override
 void initState() {
   provider.getAppIntroItems();
   super.initState();
 }

 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   //provider = Provider.of<AppIntroProvider>(context); //If I don't use GetIt DI
   return Scaffold(
     body: Consumer<AppIntroProvider>(
       builder: (context, appInfoProvider, child) => appInfoProvider
                   .appIntroItemsDao ==
               null
           ? Container(
               color: Colors.red,
             )
           : MyDataListWidget(),
     ),
   );
 }
```

My Question is

1. What is the purpose of using FutureBuilder instead of using Consumer?
2. What is the different?
3. What is right and more efficient way to implement API call?

Answer (score 0):

FutureBuilder is just a simple widget that handles some of the operations such as fetching the future in init state in the end you can use both of them.

I usually use FutureBuilder if I want to deal with different states such as Loading, Error, HasData it makes it easier to control them in the builder function

Consumer just allows you to access your state management data.

Also if you don't use FutureBuilder you have to maintain a loading state such as setting it to loading when you first start the request and then setting it to false after it's done. This can be useful if you want to use the loading state in somewhere

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So how to access if you want state management data. Just wrap consumer to Future Builder? And How to do if you want more states like no internet connection?

Comment: To handle no internet connection i suggest using a package like connectivity_plus  you can keep using locator and GetIt wrapping Consumer to FutureBuilder can also be a good alternative